# Returning JSON from URL in Sinatra Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra

```ruby
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'httparty'

set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
set :port, 8080

get '/' do
    response = HTTParty.get('http://rubygems.org/api/v1/versions/httparty.json')
    puts response[0]["numbers"]
end
```

I'm having trouble converting the data from a URL into json format using sinatra. It's currently displaying nothing in my browser window. Any tips why?

Comment: Please post your current *response* value. Most likely, you need to call JSON#parse on it if it isn't already JSON.

Comment: `puts` returns `nil`, which is what Sinatra will try use to create the page body, so that‘s probably what‘s happening. You likely just need to remove `puts`.

Comment: Btw. there are no `"numbers"` keys in the response. What is the expected output?

Comment: The return should be this

[
  {
    "number":"0.7.8",
    "built_at":"2011-06-07T00:00:00Z",
    "prerelease":false,
    "downloads_count":22720,
    ...
  },
  ...
]

I'm trying to replicate the result from this page 
https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/its-time-to-httparty

Comment: Wrap the response in a String. Parse it from JSON to a Hash. Use "number" rather than "numbers" as a key.